# react-admin - Forget list filters after redirection

Tags: react-redux, react-admin

With `react-admin` we can [filter lists results](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#filters).
When going on another page, and going back to the list, previous filters are still applied. (A strange point is that filters don't appear in URL hash)

Demo:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/

[image: Filters are memorized after redirection]

Is this a `react-admin` or `redux` behavior?

I want to have a fresh result list each time I load it.

I have two ideas to do it:

1. I know children of `<List/>` receive a `setFilter` function in their props. Maybe I could call `setFilter({})` in method `componentWillUnmount()` of each child (`<Datagrid/>`)?
2. Call `react-admin` [action `changeListParams()`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/actions/listActions.ts#L17) in each `componentWillUnmount()` of my list modules.

Is there a better solution? I can't believe the amazing team building this awesome framework didn't think of this use case!

Thanks!